# Java BigDecimal - explanation needed

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal, floating-accuracy

I was using BigDecimal, but I am still getting different results for two different (mathematically identical) expressions:

First Expression: PI - (10^(-14)/PI)

Second Expression: (PI^2 - 10^(-14))/PI

To put it more simply, here is the equation: [image: Equation with PI]

```
package set1;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class FloatingLaws {
    final static BigDecimal PI = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI);
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(firstExpression());
        System.out.println(secondExpression());

    }

    private static BigDecimal secondExpression() {
        return PI.subtract((BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10, -14)).divide(PI,50,RoundingMode.CEILING)));

    }

    private static BigDecimal firstExpression() {
        return (PI.multiply(PI).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10, -14)))).divide(PI, 50,RoundingMode.CEILING);
    }

}
```

After executing this code, no matter how big is rounding, last digit is always different. In my case I get these two results:

```
3.14159265358978981690113816209304300915191180404867
3.14159265358978981690113816209304300915191180404866
```

My question is why is this happening and is it solvable?

Comment: Does this really concern you so much?

Comment: Yes it really does :)

Comment: I've never used `BigDecimal`, but I see a lot of "rounding mode" in your code. Rounding _in the middle_ of a calculation is never a good idea (in real math where precision isn't limited by memory) because you aren't going to get an exact answer.

Comment: As @Arc676 mentioned try rounding at the end !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because You are doing this:

`pi - ((10^-4)/pi)`<- only the part in bracket is ceiled,

which is different from

`((pi^2-10^-14)/pi)`<- where the whole expression is ceiled.

You use BigDecimal and you have rounding mode CEILING with precision 50. In both of your expressions the ceiling is applied when you divide by PI number. So if you divide by PI eager like in first expression, then you could get less accurate results - because you CEIL intermediate value, before your formula fully execute, so you loose the CEILED part from the divide by PI operation and this in further computation creates the "error" effect.
When you divide by PI last, like in second expression, you use more accurate formula, which is ceiling only the result, not intermediate value like in first expression, so it calculates more preciselly, rounding only the result and not intermediate value.

Answer (score 3):

The `BigDecimal.subtract` method always produces exact difference between two `BigDecimal` numbers, without rounding. On the other hand `BigDecimal.divide` usually rounds the result. In your case you are use `CEILING` rounding mode which rounds up (towards +infinity). When you calculate `a-ceil(b/a)`, you are essentially rounding down the whole result (assuming that `a` is already rounded), while calculating `ceil((a*a-b)/a)` you're rounding up. That's why `firstExpression()` is bigger. Were you using `HALF_EVEN` rounding, the result would be the same. Were you using `FLOOR` mode, the result would be opposite.

Also take a look to what is `BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI);`:

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI));
> 3.141592653589793
```

It's not even close to the actual PI number (given the fact that you need 50 digits). You should define PI explicitly like this:

```
final static BigDecimal PI = new BigDecimal("3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510");
```

Now the result is the following:

```
3.14159265358979005536378154537278750652190194908786
3.14159265358979005536378154537278750652190194908785
```

Which is quite different from yours one.

Comment: Actually, to get better results, it often makes sense to use a precision of a little more than you need, e.g. `desiredPrecision + 5`, and only to round (preferrably `HALF_UP`) at the very end. That way you can even calculate a cosine (using Taylor series with lots of additions and divisions) to the precision you need.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your program to try all rounding modes java knows.
Running under oracle jdk 8.72, i get equal results for the rounding modes HALF_UP, HALF_DOWN and HALF_EVEN. But Krzysztof is right, since you are not rounding in the same places, errors are bound to pop up.

```
public class FloatingLaws {
    final static BigDecimal PI = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (RoundingMode roundingMode : RoundingMode.values()) {
            System.out.println(roundingMode);
            System.out.println("Equal? "+firstExpression(roundingMode).equals(secondExpression(roundingMode)));
            System.out.println(firstExpression(roundingMode));
            System.out.println(secondExpression(roundingMode));
        }

    }

    private static BigDecimal secondExpression(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    return PI.subtract((BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10, -14)).divide(PI, 50, roundingMode)));

    }

    private static BigDecimal firstExpression(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    return (PI.multiply(PI).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10, -14)))).divide(PI, 50, roundingMode);
    }

}
```

Comment: UP, DOWN, CEILING, and FLOOR tend to have worse rounding errors because they can make a difference of almost 1 in the last preserved digit. The HALF_UP, HALF_DOWN, and HALF_EVEN modes make a difference of at most half in the last preserved digits, so they should tend to get better results.